# returnUrl not working in DocuSign

Tags: api, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign for my form posting. I want the docusign to redirect to my own thankyoupage.htm after the document has been signed by the user.
I used the syntax 
https://test.docusign.net/SigningPage.aspx?ID=12313331&returnUrl= 'https://thankyoupage.htm'

But it is not working.
What is the current syntax for redirecting using returnUrl?

Answer (score 1):

The return URL can be set via your account configuration or in the brand being using by the envelope (via Landing Pages -> Sign Complete).

Setting the returnUrl is done for captive signing use cases where you make a POST request for a signing view URL. I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to do here. If setting the URL via account config does not help, then you'll need to provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the commnet jenny.
I am talking about setting the returnUrl when I make a POST request to docusign through my webApplication.
How can i achieve it?

Comment: Hi, sorry didn't respond sooner. Not sure if you still have this problem, but in that case you make the POST request (e.g. {{baseUrl}}/envelopes/{{envelopeID}}/views/recipient) for the signing view URL and then have the returnUrl defined in the body of the request along with the recipient information. This is assuming you created the envelope with the recipient defined as an embedded user in the first place.